# Is there a way to load a file from Resources and then deserialize it through BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to make a system to save and load levels not in scenes. I am happy with the current system which looks like that:

```
        string path = Application.dataPath + "/Levels/" + name + ".lvl";
        if (File.Exists (path)) {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter ();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream (path, FileMode.Open);
            LevelInformation data = formatter.Deserialize (stream) as LevelInformation;
            stream.Close ();
            return data;
        } else {
            Debug.LogError ("No level found at " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However, I would like it so that the player can't see and tweak any levels that are official and not custom, so I decided to put official levels in the assets and load them via Resources.Load(). Like that:

```
    public static LevelInformation LoadLevelOfficial (string name) {
        Object levelFile = Resources.Load("/Levels/" + name + ".lvl");
        if (levelFile) {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter ();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream (levelFile, FileMode.Open);
            LevelInformation data = formatter.Deserialize (stream) as LevelInformation;
            stream.Close ();
            return data;
        } else {
            Debug.LogError ("No official level called " + name + "can be found in the game files!");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However, Unity tells me I can't use an Object variable levelFile and instead expects me to use some IntPtr. Is there a way to convert to it to IntPtr or how else can I deserialize an object I load from resources?

Comment: Can you share your error log as well?

Comment: Sure.

`Assets/Resources/Scripts/SaveSys/SaveSystem.cs(100,40): error CS1503: Argument '#1' cannot convert 'UnityEngine.Object' expression to type 'System.IntPtr'`

Answer (score 2):

You could load your file as [`TextAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html) and use e.g.

```
TextAsset levelFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Levels/" + name);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(levelFile.bytes))
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter ();
    var data = (LevelInformation)formatter.Deserialize (stream);
    return data;
}
```

**Note** however:

> If you're using the text asset to contain **binary data**, you should make sure the file has the **`.bytes`** extension. For any other of the extentions the TextImporter will try to strip nonascii characters if it is unable to parse the file as an utf8 string.

For unknown reasons, they removed the quoted text from the [documentation page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset-bytes.html), although it is still relevant.

---

**UPDATE**

**In general [STOP USING BINARYFORMATTER!!!](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems like Resources.Load() can't be used to load custom extensions at all, as per documentation: "If the file at path is of a type that cannot be converted to T, also returns null".

Will having .bytes extension help?

Comment: Yes, I had to use rename levels to .bytes extension, and remove the first forward slash and extension at Resources.Load():

`TextAsset levelFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Levels/" + name);`

It now works. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can mark the answer as the selected answer to help the others.